# I have a bitmap in an activity, how can i restore its state after Activity reloads

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have an app in which user can draw using finger. But after drawing if user changes oreintation of screen, bitmap looses all the arcs. I tried to set in that activity
onConfigchange="screensize|orientation" but it did'nt worked

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    outState.putInt("value",10);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}       

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    int mySaveValue=0;
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    mySaveValue = savedInstanceState.getInt("value");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) to save the state of your drawing, save every value which will be used to draw it again.
when orientation is changed, you will get a callback in onRestoreInstanceState, fetch all the values from bundle and set to your view.
e.g, if you need to save an int value and retrieve it later, do following:-

Comment: can you please explain for bitmap case